# What do these two sentences together mean?

Tags: sentence

> He does not know anything. He pretends ignorance

I have to join these two sentences without using **and**, **but** and **so**, but i do not understand their combined meaning. It seems senseless to me. How can one pretend ignorance when he does not know anything?

I want to know what the two sentences together mean.

Comment: You don't say whether you need to join them with a single word; but *He does not know anything* **therefore I doubt that** *he pretends ignorance* would make sense. You can imagine an interrogator saying this about a suspect to his superior, for instance.

Comment: "He does not know anything, still he pretends ignorance".

Comment: "he does not know anything - that is, he pretends ignorance"  The first sentence can be the same as the second, in that the first sentence is what he *means* in the second sentence.

Comment: @Megha The two main clauses are different in meaning and one cannot be added as a paraphrase of the other. If you're implying that the first main clause is being used ironically, scare quotes are needed.

Comment: It's not that he does not know anything – he pretends ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the meaning of the two sentences together is going to be created by the way you choose to join them.

Although he does not know anything, he pretends ignorance.

The although sets up a bit of a mystery. He doesn't know anything, so why does he pretend ignorance?

He pretends ignorance; unfortunately, he doesn't know anything.

This suggests that he thinks he has knowledge that he doesn't really have, and it sets up an irony that we know this about him while he doesn't.

You would get different results with other conjunctions: however, consequently, moreover, because, for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use (nevertheless)? or yet(might be better I think) to join both sentences:

He does not know anything, yet he pretends ignorance.